# Show that ABQC is a cyclic quadrilateral & $\triangle BPD $ is isosceles

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

[image]

Hi can anyone help me out here , Because I struggling in iii & iv

What I have done so far

$i.\angle BAC=2a$

$ii. \angle BAQ= \angle QAC$

$\therefore \angle BCQ = \angle QAC$ (alternate segment theorem)

& $ \angle BCQ = \angle QAC $

Comment: This is just one of the thousand variations of a well-known lemma: given a triangle $ABC$, the internal angle bisector through $A$ and the perpendicular bisector of the $BC$ side meet on the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

For (iii) :

All we need to prove is that $\angle{BAQ}=\angle{BCQ}$. Use that $\triangle{BQC}$ is an isosceles triangle.

For (iv) :

We have that $\angle{BDP}=\angle{BAP}$ and that $\angle{DBP}=\angle{DAP}$ from which $\angle{BDP}=\angle{DBP}$ follows.